# GoDaddy DNS frustrations.

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, godaddy

My mate has a domain he bought through GoDaddy.com - at some point he changed the name server. Now we need to get the dns back under the control of GoDaddy.com. He doesn't remember doing this so he can't help me at all.

How can I get it changed back?

Comment: How about calling GoDaddy support?

Comment: i prefer making my questions more public - the company is more likely to fix the issues if people do that. calling them keeps me nice and hidden away, just where they want complaints

Comment: GoDaddy is unlikely to change *anything* unless it's motivated by either 1) annoying its customers or 2) increasing their profit margins.

Comment: This isn't a complaint forum

Comment: @Nixphoe no - ITS A HELP FORUM!!!

Comment: So you think someone at GoDaddy is monitoring this web site and is going to initiate a support request on your behalf, based on your question here?

Comment: @cvista, **ServerFault is not a forum**, it is a Q&A site. Please see the [FAQ] for details.

Comment: @cvista - You're kind of right, this is a Q&A site. It's for professional systems administrators to ask detailed questions about issues with their environments. Any professional administrator having an issue with a specific vendor's practices or policy would be going through that vendor, not coming to a completely unrelated site to air grievances.

Comment: @cvista - which one was it; did you friend change the DNS server at some point or can he not remember doing this? your question states both things.

Comment: GoDaddy *are* useless, though.  I suggest you change provider to one with $clue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to the GoDaddy account.
2. Hover over Domains, and select Domain Management
3. Choose the domain from the list provided by clicking on the domain name
4. You should now be in Domain Details - click "Set Nameservers" under the Nameservers section (which is under Domain Information)

From there you can choose to park or if you have a hosting account you can choose that in this pop-up as well. If you want GD to take over the DNS hosting you do not have to specific any of their nameservers. Choose one of the above mentioned only.

Answer (score 1):

In the GoDaddy console he will be able to change the DNS back  to hosted by GoDaddy. Them update the A records accordingly. Its all done thru the  GoDaddy console.

Comment: but i can't find amnywhere what to put in those? what are godaddy's name servers?

Comment: My Products section, select Domain Manager then Set Nameservers.

Comment: it doesn't say anywhere there what the frikin name servers are!! i have been all over that page. like a rash.

Comment: "I have a hosting account with these domains "

Comment: http://help.godaddy.com/article/664#reghere

Comment: done that - name server stayed the same...